# Simple looking equation hard to solve

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to solve the equation for s

$1=(\frac{1}{5})^s+(\frac{2}{5})^s$

without using numerical methods.

Comment: $s \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: We can rewrite this as $5^s = 1 + 2^s$.  It seems clear that no integer will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you have to solve it numerically, and you will get

$$5^s-2^s =1 \implies
s \approx 0.56389552425993647949039294593795656551521173050995529859280838012046620052281974$$

You can also use a [geometrical](http://www4a.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5%5Es%E2%88%922%5Es+plot) interpretation though.